# Excel VBA: custom collection duplicated items

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a class which contains a custom collection class. The collection class is filled with items when the parent class is initialized. The problem is that when I iterate through the items of the collection, all items have the properties of the last item added. The items should be associated with cells in the ActiveSheet, each item has a Name and Range properties. The Name is the value of the cell, the Range is the Range. So in cells A1:D1 I have values ID, Q1, Q2, Q3 and when I create an instance of the parent class I expect the members of the collection to have names ID, Q1, Q2, Q3 and Range A1, B1, C1, D1. When I iterate however, the output shows Q3, Q3, Q3, Q3 and $D$1, $D$1, $D$1, $D$1.

Where is the problem?

The code below:

```
Sub test()

    Dim Sample As Sample
    Set Sample = New Sample

    Dim fld As New Field

    For Each fld In Sample.Fields
        Debug.Print fld.Name; vbTab; fld.Range.Address
    Next

End Sub
```

The Field class:

```
Private pName As String
Private pRange As Range

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(value As String)
    pName = value
End Property

Public Property Set Range(rng As Range)
    Set pRange = rng
End Property

Public Property Get Range() As Range
    Set Range = pRange
End Property
```

The Fields class (the custom collection):

```
Private pFields As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pFields = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set pFields = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = pFields.[_NewEnum]
End Function

Public Sub Add(fld As Field)
    pFields.Add fld
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(Index As Variant)
    pFields.Remove Index
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(Index As Variant) As Field
    Set Item = pFields.Item(Index)
End Property

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = pFields.Count
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Set pFields = New Collection
End Sub
```

And the Sample class (containing the Fields collection class):

```
Private pFields As Fields

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pFields = New Fields
    Initialize_Fields
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set pFields = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Fields() As Fields
    Set Fields = pFields
End Property

Private Sub Initialize_Fields()

    Dim rngHeaders As Range, rngCell As Range
    Set rngHeaders = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows(1)

    For Each rngCell In rngHeaders.Cells
        Dim NewField As New Field
        NewField.Name = rngCell.Value2
        Set NewField.Range = rngCell

        pFields.Add NewField
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Changed this:

```
For Each rngCell In rngHeaders.Cells
    Dim NewField As New Field
    NewField.Name = rngCell.Value2
    Set NewField.Range = rngCell

    pFields.Add NewField
Next rngCell
```

To this:

```
Dim NewField As Field

For Each rngCell In rngHeaders.Cells
    Set NewField = New Field

    NewField.Name = rngCell.Value2
    Set NewField.Range = rngCell

    pFields.Add NewField
Next rngCell
```